# Подсчёт количества строк в mysql таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, товарищи гуру-программисты.
Собственно нужно чтоб ЭТО считало количество строк в таблице и выводило их последовательно (вверху страницы самые свежие записи, чем дальше чем старее).

```
<?php 
        include("header-logo.php");         /*присоединение хедера*/
        echo "<br>";                                                                
        $db_host = 'localhost';         /*имя хоста*/
        $db_name = 'hoptoh13_workdays';     /*имя базы*/
        $db_username = 'hoptoh13_andrew';        /*имя пользователя*/
        $db_password = 'SDFADSG';               /*пасс */
        $db_table_to_show = 'news';             /*имя таблицы*/

        $conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name) or die       ('Невозможно открыть базу'); 
          // присоединение к БД

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `news`";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          // присоединение к таблице


        $afh = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `news`")); /*количество строк в таблице*/

        while ($afh > 0) /*цикл для вывода из таблицы строк в обратном порядке (через минус)*/
            {
                $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=$a");
                $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);



                echo "<div class='news-telo'><span class='news-datetime'>  ".$myrow["datatime"].
                    "  </span><img src='".$myrow["image"]."' class='news-image'>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <span class='news-text'>".$myrow["text"]."</span>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    </div>
                    <br>";

                $a = $a-1;
            }


            include("footer.php");  /*футер*/      
     ?>
```

Комментарии пишу чтоб не запутаться т.к. совсем недавно начал увлекаться темой кодинга. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что написано не так?
PHP матерится на строчку

```
$afh = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `news`"));
```

выдаёт

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in public_html/news.php on line 28
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in public_html/news.php on line 28
```

Также буду благодарен за хорошие мануалы с примерами по написанию простых команд для версий php 5.5 и выше

Comment: количество строк из таблицы можно получить `select count(*) from news` а вывести строки в обратном порядке `select * from news order by id desc`. А id могут идти с разрывами, так что количество строк и максимальный id не имеют друг к другу никакого отношения. А получение всех строк (select *) ради узнавания их количества и перебор записей в цикле получая каждую отдельным запросом - работают раз в 50 медленнее, чем правильные запросы. Изучайте SQL и старайтесь получить от БД все, что она умеет делать, а умеет она практически все

Comment: так если не использовать переменную с числом строк в таблице, какое условие дать для while?

Comment: А литература особо и не нужна. описания функций вполне достаточно, тем более там ближе к концу полно примеров. вот например посмотрите внимательно на http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php  в том виде как вы ее используете ей надо передавать 2 параметра, а не 1.

Comment: почитаю, спасибо за инфу

Comment: просто `while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` БД ведь вернет строки уже в правильном порядке если применить order by

Answer (score 0):

Ругается на эту строку

```
$afh = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `news`"));
```

так как `mysqli_query` принимает 2 параметра (линк на коннект к бд и запрос). Добавьте линк и не будет ругаться. Также можно в `mysqli_num_rows` передать уже существующую переменную `$result`.

Почитать подробнее - [ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

---

также:

- Нет инициализации переменной `$a` ;
- Запрос вставлять в цикл - дурной тон, избегайте.
- Если запрос в переменной `$sql` используется только для определения кол-ва записей, рекомендую написать так:

  `include("header-logo.php");
  echo "<br>";
  $db_host = 'localhost';
  $db_name = 'hoptoh13_workdays';
  $db_username = 'hoptoh13_andrew';
  $db_password = 'SDFADSG';
  $db_table_to_show = 'news';`

  `$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name) or die ('Невозможно открыть базу');`

  `$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(*) FROM news"));`

  `$cnt = $row[0];`

  `$arr = array();`

  `// Нет переменной $a - обратите внимание
  $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=$a ORDER BY datatime desc");`

  ```
  while(list($datatime,$image,$text) = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
      array_push($arr,array("datatime"=>$datatime, "image"=>$image, "text"=>$text));
  }
  ```

  `if($cnt > 0)
  {`

  `for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)`
    `{`
      `echo "<div class='news-telo'><span class='news-datetime'>  ".$arr[$i]["datatime"].`
               `"</span><img src='".$arr[$i]["image"]."' class='news-image'>
              <br>
              <br>
              <span class='news-text'>".$arr[$i]["text"]."</span>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              </div>
              <br>";`
     `}`
  }

  `include("footer.php");  /*футер*/`

Comment: согласен, забыл переписать + добавил вывод новостей в массив за условием и цикл для заполнения всеми элементами массива

Comment: +++++++++++++++